# Why seem to sell and be mafkir chametz?

Tags: transactions, chametz-leaven, bitul-batel-null, selling-mechirat-chametz

My understanding is that we do both of the following:

- We (appoint a rabbi as an agent to) sell our *chametz* to a gentile. This sale takes place the morning of the day before *Pesach*, before the prohibition of owning *chametz* kicks in.
- We renounce ownership in our *chametz*, declaring it ownerless. This also takes place the morning of the day before *Pesach*, before the prohibition of owning *chametz* kicks in.

Is seems, then, that whichever of these takes effect first renders us free of ownership of *chametz*, and whichever we do second therefore has no effect (unless one's acquired *chametz* meanwhile, an unlikely scenario). So why do the latter act (if, I mean, it has no effect anyway)?

Comment: Possible effect: We say two Kol Chamirot for a similar reason as well - you need to eat on Erev Pesach, and what if they sell before you eat? That's what the second renounce might also accomplish; that you should own your food that you saved for today (provided of course that this food is not included in the sale).

Comment: similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/113300/170

Answer (score 6):

[Shulchan Aruch O.C. 448:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2188) rules that *chometz* which is found in your home after *Pesach*, even if you nullified it, is forbidden.  The Tur there (cited by Magen Avraham and Taz) explains that we are worried that a person will say he nullified it even if he didn't.  This isn't a problem for those crumbs that you don't want anyways.  But for that box of cheerios you were planning on enjoying, it's a problem.

There is another reason that could be used to explain why it would be forbidden to use your *chometz* after you nullified it. If you nullify your *chometz* and declare that you consider it to be like dirt, and then start munching on it 9 days later, it would be a little bit of a contradiction to your nullification of it. (I can't remember where I saw this idea explicitly, but it is similar to the idea (Taz O.C. 442:8) that if you eat *chometz* which is degraded enough to not require getting rid of it, אחשביה, you have given it importance and reinstated its negated status.)

If you sell your *chometz*, you don't have these issues.

Selling your *chometz* would certainly not be prevented by having done *bittul* according to many Rishonim.  While Tosefos ([Pesachim 4b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=4b&format=pdf) s.v. *mid'oraisa*) seems to hold that *bittul* accomplishes *hefker*, the implication of Rashi (ibid, s.v. *b'bittul b'alma*) and the explicit claim of the Ramban (Novelae to Pesachim 4b) is that *bittul* does not effect *hefker* and you still own your *chometz*.  As the Ramban explains it, with *bittul* you are declaring acquiescense to the Torah's prohibition of *chometz* and submitting to the *Torah*'s removal of *chometz* from your ownership.  This happens after your sale takes effect.  According to this view, you can "nullify" your *chometz* and still have ownership until the Torah removes it from your ownership at the 6th (or, Rabbinically, 5th) hour.

You would still want to do *bittul*, either to fulfill the *mitzvah* of *tashbisu* according to those who hold it is a fulfillment of the *mitzvah* (Ramban novelae to Pesachim, among others), or just to fulfill the Rabbinical enactment.

Comment: Regarding your added paragraph, see the [Ramo O.C. 434:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2154).

Comment: @Yishai there is no Rema there.  I assume you meant 434:2?  If the Rema wants to take into account the opinion of Tosefos doesn't mean you would discount the opinions of the other Rishonim.

Comment: @yEz, How do you know the Ramo takes into account anything but the opinion of Tosfos (the Ran and the Rosh agree with Hefker as well)? It isn't really a matter of "discounting" it is just that the question then still stands. Why is the Ramo's concern ignored when it comes to selling, but relevant when it comes to burning? Also, someone explicitly paskening like Rashi/Ramban here would enhance your point as well.

Comment: @Yishai The Rema is being _stringent_ in the order of _bittul_ / _s'reifa_ to fulfill that view.  Why do you see that he would disregard the other direction?  And that wasn't even my point - my point is why would you discount that view in light of a Rema?  I would be able to sell after _bittul_, and want to go ahead and do that, to satisfy other opinions.

Comment: @yEz, I'm not seeing how you know that. Here is an alternative reading: The Rama holds that bittul is effective immediately according to all opinions, whatever its mechanics. I'm not advocating either way, I'm just trying to flesh out the point better.

Comment: @Yishai See the Ramban inside.  It is impossible to learn like that.  You could suggest the Rema didn't see the Ramban and therefore understood him in a way which is explicitly against what he says, if that makes you happy. And even if he did, the Ramban explicitly says it isn't removing it from your _reshus_, so the Rema would have to ignore that too.  Basically, you can make the Rema an _am ha'aretz_ if you want, but I'd rather not.

Comment: @yEz, I don't know how you see that in the Ramban. You can call me an Am Haretz if you want, I don't mind, but I'm not seeing how the Ramban is "clear" on that.

Comment: @Yishai I didn't call you an am ha'aretz.  I just said that putting such a reading into the Ramban would be making the Rema unfamiliar with the Ramban if he means to accomodate his position.  See the Ramban's comparison to bittul reshus for eruv, and avoda zara, both of which he makes clear have nothing to do with losing ownership. And his point that _hefker_ is _assur_ on Shabbos because of changing ownership while _bittul_ is permitted would apply to whatever _bittul_ is if it similarly makes him no longer the owner.

Comment: And his justification of it not being called "לך" because he is אינו רוצה בקיומו would be unnecessary if it isn't his after _bittul_ (which is what Ramban understands to be the main point of Tosefos).

Comment: @yEz, I didn't mean to say you called me an ע"ה, just that you said not seeing it in the Ramban would make someone one, and I don't see it. Why is this effective time of the bittul only at Chatzos? Where does the Ramban say that? He says he makes it that he no longer wants the Chametz to exists. Rather problematic if you intend to sell it for cash in a couple of hours, no?

Comment: @Yishai Whatever time you want to say it takes effect (the Ramban explains that בדין הוא שלא יעבור עליו בכלום, אלא שהתורה עשאתו כאלו הוא ברשותו לעבור עליו בשני לאוין, מפני שדעתו עליו והוא רוצה בקיומו and he is being הסכימה דעתו לדעת תורה ויצא לבטלו - I don't know what the alternative explanation and read of those words is other than that he is acquiescing to the Torah removing it from his _reshus_, which happens later - see the whole paragraph starting אלא כך אני אומר), it certainly is still his and he could sell it if he owns it.

Answer (score 3):

Shulchan Aruch HaRav (OC [431:4](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/431/4)) writes that the Chachamim don't allow you to retain Chametz on your property during Pesach for two reasons: 1) You may not mean it when you say it is hefker and 2) you may forget and go eat it.

So if you are going to keep Chametz in your closet over Pesach, hefker won't be enough, it has to be sold. Selling Chametz is a much more recent practice.

Even if you have no Chametz (as was standard say 1,000 or more years ago) as the Chachamim didn't let you keep Chametz, hefker or not, they still required you to do the Bittul Chametz ([Pesachim 6b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=6b&format=pdf)). Shulchan Aruch HaRav (OC [434:6](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/434/6)) explains that this is in case you missed a piece that isn't nullfied automatically and you happen to find it on Pesach - if you don't destroy it right away, you would be in violation of the Torah prohibition of owning Chametz.

In any event the point is that Bitul Chametz was a specific institution that the Chachamim made even though it is expected that you own no Chametz. So the subsequent practice of selling chametz (even if such a sale was actually to include the edible piece of Chametz that fell into a far corner - I don't think all sales are so thorough) doesn't remove the practice established by the Chachaimim to do Bittul Chametz.

Comment: How can you sell something that you did bittul on?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm pretty sure that the bittul doesn't help, even according the the view that the main issue is that you may eat it. It is one thing to do bittul stam, it is another to lock it away in a closet and say "bittul". But since you intend to sell it, then you aren't including it in the bittul.

Answer (score 1):

The formulation for bitul chametz is
is

> כל חמירא וחמיעא דאיכא ברשותי, דחזיתיה ודלא חזיתיה, דבערתיה ודלא בערתיה, לבטיל ולהוי הפקר כעפרא דארעא"

Significant amounts of chametz cannot be nullified since it wouldn't realistically be possible to see it as "dust."

Comment: This answers half the question. Why then do we do bitul if we're selling it?

Comment: Unless you mean that the selling is for significant amounts, and bitul is for insignificant stuff? If so, you should probably make that explicit in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

He might not mean the bittul sincerely - therefore, the bittul is not enough.

Selling chametz is something that is controversial. People sell chametz so that they will be able to eat it after Pesach. Also, many don't sell chametz gamur.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michoel. You could improve it by adding sources.