# Is deer antler velvet kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, health-safety-shmira

Is deer antler velvet kosher? I'm referring to this:
http://www.esupplements.com/products/dvx-pro-liquid/?mobile=1

Or this:
http://www.esupplements.com/products/deer-antler-velvet-pro/?mobile=1

I remember learning somewhere that bones of non kosher animals are permitted because no one eats a bone. Also does using the spray product and spraying it under the tongue constitute eating, the spray under the tongue is meant for the substance to be absorbed under the tongue rather than it being swallowed. 
Please let me know on both products and in general deer antler velvet extract.

Thanks

Comment: Deer is a kosher animal. (It would need Shechita of course.)

Comment: I'm saying would it also apply to non shected properly deer, which that's usually the case with these products.

Comment: I don't get why a non-kosher bone would  be permitted as dogs eat bones and usually dogs are used as the test as to whether a product is classified as food.

Comment: Does the deer need to be slaughtered if one is not eating it? I don't see any problem, either way. Jews wear mink and fox fur coats, coming from non-kosher animals.

Comment: @DanF In the case here he is eating it.

Comment: @CashCow Not really. It's an estimation. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56900/759

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/i/5204.htm#22 but other Rishonim seem to argue, see Yabia Omer YD 8:11:6.

Comment: @DanF That Jews do something does not mean it pleases God to do so (Lev. 5:2, Lev. 7:21).   If he is guilty for doing so unknowingly, how much more so, knowingly.

Comment: If you can provide the yabia Omer text that talks about it that would be great

Comment: If there was, historically, an uncertainty or discrepancy pertaining to a matter of the law, and the judges have made a ruling on that, it would be presumptuous to contradict them (Deut . 15); I think that was why you inquired.  I assume there are judges today for such as well. My comment to DanF was in regard to using what Jews do or don't do as a justification for what one does or does not do. This would be a poor standard to hold up; for what if what the Jew does is wrong by the standard of God? A Jew might have acted according to God's law & God ordained ruling...or not

Comment: @CashCow that is only by chometz and tuma but by forbidden things it is only forbidden if it is food (as it says a traifa you should give to the ger (toshav) so it needs to be edible to be forbidden, and this is also the whole bases that nosen tam lpgam is kosher)

Comment: deer antlers can be removed from a deer without killing the deer. it's not likely they are killing the deer. this would be very inefficient as a love deer can provide more antler while a dead one cannot