# Fitting for an animal to eat besides a dog

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, passover, halacha-theory, animals

In many halachos about food (Kashrus, owning Chametz on Pesach, etc.), a standard for determining if something retains its status as food is if it is "fitting for a dog to eat."

What about other animals? If a pig or chicken would eat it, does it count? Is a dog just the archetype of a non-picky eater, or is there something specific about the dog that gives it that status?

Comment: [Avoda Zarah 67b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=67b&format=pdf) and [Bechorot 23b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=32&daf=23b&format=pdf) (and tosfot there, but cf [Challah 1:8](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%90_%D7%97)) are probably relevant but also consider http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56900/759

Comment: Maybe cause they eat their own feces.  And they are 'starving' & eat anything.

Comment: @user, in other words the archetype. But the tosfos in brachos that doubleaa referenced seems to say there is a special limud from a posuk specifically for dogs.

Comment: @Yishai *bechoros not brachos

Comment: I'm not realy in the sugya there but isn't that a limud specificaly for tumaah?

Comment: we learn this from the verse "לכלב תשליחון" it seems that dogs is Davka. "לגר" is also Davka. I think that if we fing a domestic animal who eat thinks that dog cannot eat, perhaps pig or Hyena or alligator, this is not counted, because you cannot prove this, despite that it is a Kula generally

Comment: @user the first part of tosfos is saying there is a verse for achila which is not the source for tuma. The verse alone I don't find dispositive, as the verse can have reasons like the ones you site. But the way tosphos frames it, would seem to be a dog specifically.

Comment: The Rambam in hilchos de'os perek 3 halacha 2 writes, "Therefore, don't eat that which your palette desires like a dog and a donkey".